# Create nested list from list in python

Tags: python, list, arraylist, nested

Need to get nested lists from the list in python

```
list_values=[('BNB', '161221'),
 ('BNB', '171221'),
 ('BNB', '241221'),
 ('BNB', '280122'),
 ('BNB', '311221'),
 ('BTC', '161221'),
 ('BTC', '171221'),
 ('BTC', '241221'),
 ('BTC', '250222'),
 ('BTC', '250322'),
 ('BTC', '280122'),
 ('BTC', '311221')]
```

The output of lists needed is

```
List_op=[[('BNB', '161221'),
 ('BNB', '171221'),
 ('BNB', '241221'),
 ('BNB', '280122'),
 ('BNB', '311221')],
[('BTC', '161221'),
 ('BTC', '171221'),
 ('BTC', '241221'),
 ('BTC', '250222'),
 ('BTC', '250322'),
 ('BTC', '280122'),
 ('BTC', '311221')]]
```

I have tried with some list comprehension methods, but couldnt get this. Help is appreciated.

Comment: Please share what you tried and explain what the issue was. Also, are you trying to find something simple or something fast? And is the data you really need this to work on large? Are there more than two values for the first element of the tuple, or always 2?

Comment: new_list=[]
for i in filtered_final_product_list:
    if str(i[0])==str(i[1]):
        new_list.append(i)
print(new_list)

but this doesnt append and the variables of list is not static. there are many elements @Grismar

Comment: There are more than two elements,  data needed is small list only and need only simple working answer.. @Grismar

Comment: Are you trying to group tuples with the same first value? From the question, your exact intention is somewhat unclear.

Comment: yes..@UnderscoreA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution:

```
from collections import defaultdict

list_values = [
    ('BNB', '161221'),
    ('BNB', '171221'),
    ('BNB', '241221'),
    ('BNB', '280122'),
    ('BNB', '311221'),
    ('BTC', '161221'),
    ('BTC', '171221'),
    ('BTC', '241221'),
    ('BTC', '250222'),
    ('BTC', '250322'),
    ('BTC', '280122'),
    ('BTC', '311221')
]

# a dict might be a better data type here
result = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in list_values:
    result[k].append(v)
print(result)

# but if you need a list of lists instead of a dictionary:
result = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in list_values:
    result[k].append((k, v))
list_op = [*result.values()]
print(list_op)
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'BNB': ['161221', '171221', '241221', '280122', '311221'], 'BTC': ['161221', '171221', '241221', '250222', '250322', '280122', '311221']})
[[('BNB', '161221'), ('BNB', '171221'), ('BNB', '241221'), ('BNB', '280122'), ('BNB', '311221')], [('BTC', '161221'), ('BTC', '171221'), ('BTC', '241221'), ('BTC', '250222'), ('BTC', '250322'), ('BTC', '280122'), ('BTC', '311221')]]
```

Comment: You're welcome, please select the answer that works best for you and accept it with the checkmark, so that the question no longer appears as unanswered

Answer (score 0):

Not the most graceful way to do this, but you could iterate your starting list with a for each loop and build out the 2D output:

```py
list_values=[('BNB', '161221'),
 ('BNB', '171221'),
 ('BNB', '241221'),
 ('BNB', '280122'),
 ('BNB', '311221'),
 ('BTC', '161221'),
 ('BTC', '171221'),
 ('BTC', '241221'),
 ('BTC', '250222'),
 ('BTC', '250322'),
 ('BTC', '280122'),
 ('BTC', '311221')]

key = ''
List_op = []
for lv in list_values:
    if lv[0] != key:            # new key encountered
        if key != '':
            List_op.append(op)  # add previous 1D list to 2D output
        key = lv[0]             # assign new key value
        op = []                 # reinitialize 1D list
    op.append(lv)               # append current tuple to 1D list
List_op.append(op)              # add final 1D list to 2D 

print(List_op)
```

This prints:

```
[[('BNB', '161221'), ('BNB', '171221'), ('BNB', '241221'),
  ('BNB', '280122'), ('BNB', '311221')],
 [('BTC', '161221'), ('BTC', '171221'), ('BTC', '241221'),
  ('BTC', '250222'), ('BTC', '250322'), ('BTC', '280122'),
  ('BTC', '311221')]]
```

Comment: could u please explain the logic, output is fine.. Couldnt get the method..